# Cannot pass array correctly to other page in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, parameter-passing

```
    //FID is an array
     Response.Redirect("show.aspx?id=" + ID + "&name=" + NAME + "&fileid=" + FID+"&length="+j);


 //In show.aspx


 Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["fileid"].ToString();
```

I'm getting  label text as **System.String[]**

Comment: What are you expecting Label1.Text to display?

Comment: `System.String[]` is the string representation of a string array. You need to construct your url like `fid[]=item1&fid[]=item2...` if you want to pass an arary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to not pass an `array` in a query string as a parameter, but put it instead in a [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) variable.

If you really want to pass in an array, then you can make it a `comma separated string` and then pass it in, then on the second page `split` that string

**Edit:** Check the above link and here is how you can do this..

```
    Session["fileid"] = FID; // set in session in first page
     //Accessing on Second page
    String[] FID;
    FID = (String[])Session["FID"];
```

Comment: For now I'm using join Split.But can u tell me how to use Session variable please.

Comment: How to convert an string array to integer array.

Answer (score 1):

Given that FID is an array, if you want to give it the first value then you would have to do:

```
Response.Redirect("show.aspx?id=" + ID + "&name=" + NAME + "&fileid=" + (FID.Length == 1 ? FID[0]: "") +"&length="+j);
```

In my example it will send an empty string if FID has anything more or less than 1, you will have to create your own validation there depending on your requirements

If there are more than 1 values and you want to pass all the values, you will have to create loop logic, but from your example it looks like it will only hold 1 value

Answer (score 0):

That is because the ToString() method of a string[] is "System.String[]"! You would need to provide some printer to print out the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to use `Session` as per @Muhammad Akhtar.

But if you absolutely need to pass the array in the query string, you could use `String.Join()` to concatenate the array elements together -- you just have to pick a suitable delimiter.